# In Rails' rspec, how do I write/edit my test file so that examples in a specific context are run in a set order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I’m using Rails 4.2 with RSpec 3.4.0.  If I want to run all examples in the order in which the appear in a file, I can run

```
bundle exec rspec  --order defined spec/models/my_model_spec.rb
```

But what if I only want to run the examples in a specific describe block in a specific order?  It there any way I can do that by adding some attributes or making annotations in the file itself (as opposed to having to add them in on the command line)?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run the specs within a single `describe` or `context`, just add the line number of the `describe` or `context` statement to the end of the spec file name.

```
bundle exec rspec  --order defined scec/models/my_model_spec.rb:123
```

You can also run a specific example group by name using the `--example` option.

```
bundle exec rspec  --example "context name" spec/models/my_model_spec.rb
```

Though, that second choice will use a regex to find the string. So, it will find all instances of that string in any `describe`, `context`, or `it` statement.